# unable use any installed npm packages

Tags: node.js, npm, fedora-21

I'm trying to use node on my fedora 21 installation. However whenever I install a package via npm I am not able to to call that package such as gulp.

```
npm install -g gulp
```

then : `gulp run`

error:

```
zsh: command not found: gulp
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to point your global `$PATH` variable to the location of node. Otherwise, it will return that error.

Open your `.zshrc` file and ensure you see something like `PATH=/usr/bin/node:$PATH` (ensuring your directory is the proper one for node). You can find that directory location with the command `npm -g bin`.

If that doesn't work, comment below. Thanks

Comment: I've tried that but still not luck  `export PATH=/home/atbyrd/.npm/local/bin/bin:$PATH`

Comment: When you run the command `npm install -g gulp`, do you get any errors? Also, when you run the `node` command, does it return any errors?

Comment: I was able to get it to work by following [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11177954/how-do-i-completely-uninstall-node-js-and-reinstall-from-beginning-mac-os-x) and reinstalling using nvm.

Comment: Awesome. I was scratching me head with this one... sometimes you just reinstall and it works. Glad you got it working!

Answer (score 2):

The directory where npm installed gulp is not in your path. To find out where it was installed, run `npm -g bin` and make sure the directory is in your path. Alternatively, execute gulp as `$(npm -g bin)/gulp`.